# Programmatically create a Custom Content type on saving a form

Tags: 8

We have explored it and found - how to create a content type by adding the YML files in the config/install directory of a custom module. The new content type will be created when we enable the module.

But we have a use case where we need to generate content types on saving a form.
For eg: We have a custom form with a field called "Content-Type Name". On submitting the form, we need to create a new content type with that name.

We are not able to find any proper documentation for this in Drupal 8.

Comment: A content type is a config entity, you can create one like any other config entity

Comment: Also there is already an existing form for this: the original create content type form. The code itself should be a sufficient documentation for this matter.

Comment: "Also there is already an existing form for this: the original create content type form." -- pretty much this. It already exists. I can't think of a use case to reinvent the wheel here. But by all means, look at the provided answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A content type is a config entity, you can create one like any other config entity [(*)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/271126/programmatically-create-a-custom-content-type-on-saving-a-form#comment333508_271126):

```
$content_type = \Drupal\node\Entity\NodeType::create([
  'type' => $machine_name,
  'label' => $label,
]);
$content_type->save();
```